# SQL server group by show which rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called phonecalls which stores records of phone calls history from a company looks like this

```
ID    Number    Duration    Cost
-------------------------------------
1     123456    13          1
2     222222    39          1
3     333333    69          2
4     222222    36          1
```

What I want to do is get sum of duration and cost for each number.

```
SELECT 
    Number, 
    SUM(Duration) as [Total_Duration], 
    SUM(Cost) as [Total_Cost]
FROM 
    phonecalls 
GROUP BY 
    Number;
```

Now the catch is I also need which id did i included in each group by for auditing purpose so that others will know which rows are processed. So my question is how to you include ids when you do a group by?

Almighty Stackoverflow please help me.

Thanks in advance.

--EDIT:

Is it possible to get all ids with same number in one cell? something like

```
ID    Number    Total_Duration    Total_Cost
---------------------------------------------------
1     123456    13                1
2,4   222222    75                2
3     333333    69                2
```

Hope im not asking for too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `SUM OVER()` function:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2691/0)

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Number,
    Total_Duration = SUM(Duration) OVER(PARTITION BY Number),
    Total_Cost = SUM(Cost) OVER(PARTITION BY Number)
FROM phonecalls
```

---

If you want to concatenate the `ID`s, you can use `FOR XML PATH('')`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2693/0)

```
SELECT
    ID = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ID)
            FROM phonecalls
            WHERE Number = p.Number
            FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, ''),
    Number,
    Total_Duration = SUM(Duration),
    Total_Cost = SUM(Cost)
FROM phonecalls p
GROUP BY Number
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response. I have edited my question, just wondering if it is possible to have ids with same number in one cell?

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm